# Batch File to Mass Decompile .Class Files from Extracted Jar not Leaving in Original Directory

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm working on a batch file that recurs-es within a directory and called the Java Decompiler in order to decompile .class files.

For some reason or other, the files are decompiled but they don't remain in the original locations but instead the .jad files are in the location that I have called my bat file from.

My BAT file code is the following:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") do (
@echo decompiling
jad -o "%%G/*.class"
@echo decompiled

@echo renaming
ren *.jad *.java
@echo renamed
)
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.cygwin.com/install.html - Learn UNIX Shell scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you don't understand the concept of the working directory all that well.

Your batch file is executed from a specific working directory, which than calls JAD continuously from there.

You need to either change your batch file to CD (Change directory), or to move the resulting decompiled files to the location where the .class was located.

Something like this should do it:

```
move *.java "%%G/"
```

Give it a try. Additionally, you should consider moving the .class files to another location if your planning on using the source code within a project.

### Update

So your whole script for decompiling and keeping the original package structure should be the one below. I also took the liberty to add an option to delete the .class files for cleanup.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") do (
@echo decompiling
jad -o "%%G/*.class"
@echo decompiled

@echo renaming
ren *.jad *.java
@echo renamed

@echo moving...
move *.java "%%G/"
@echo moved...
)

SET /P RESULT=[Delete .class files (y/n)]
IF %RESULT% == yes do (
    FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") do (
    cd "%%G/"
    del *.class
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. However, I still don't understand why you need the move command. Why don't the files stay in the original folder/package?

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory . Your calling jad from the working directory (without CD) meaning if you have a package called "foo" your calling 'jad -o FOO/*.class' but the results are placed in current working directory (from where you execute your script).

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Jad (1.5.8g) doesn't pickup filenames with certain characters (like a dollarsign) when using a wildcard. I've modified the script to decompile files individually to get around this limitation in Jad.

I've also modified it to use the `-d` option to specify the output folder. This removes the need to performe a move operation.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") do (
    FOR %%X in ("%%G\*.class") do (
        jad -o -d "%%G" "%%X"
        ren "%%~dpnX.jad" "%%~nX.java"
    )
)

SET /P RESULT=[Delete .class files (y/n)]
IF %RESULT% == yes do (
    FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") do (
    cd "%%G\"
    del *.class
    )
)
```